# NodeJS Express Server crashes when router gets an encoded URL

Tags: node.js, express, router, encodeuricomponent

I have a NodeJS and an API that handles get requests.

```
...
var apiRoutes = express.Router();

apiRoutes.get("/filter/:name",function(req, res){
  // do something
  res.json(result);
}

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

Then in the client (not an important information but it is Angular2):

```
find(name:string): void{
    name.trim();
    this.http.get(encodeURI('http://server_address/api/filter/' + name))...
```

It works well for the parameters don't contain whitespaces, etc. In order to make it working with spaced inputs also, I used `encodeURI` function. However, when I give an input with whitespaces the server gives error:

```
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user/home/server/server.js:65:28)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Any idea what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was doing something like:

```
apiRoutes.get("/filter/:name",function(req, res){
  http.request(anotherURL + req.body.name)... 
}
```

And thought that the `name` parameter is already encoded since it was encoded in the client. However I see that I have to encode it in the server again.

```
apiRoutes.get("/filter/:name",function(req, res){
  http.request(anotherURL + encodeURI(req.body.name))... 
}
```